# Find TAGS for custom values in exif Android

Tags: java, android, exif, android-exifinterface

Hello i am trying to write custom values in EXIF of my `.jpg` images but i can't find some of the `TAG` that would be equivalent to the following :

[image]
[image]

I have tried to find the `TAG`s here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface#TAG_FOCAL_PLANE_X_RESOLUTION

But could not find the matching TAG / code to save these values using `Exif.saveAttributes(TAG, value)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Documentation on that page says: *"Note: It is recommended to use the AndroidX [ExifInterface Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface) since it is a superset of this class. In addition to the functionalities of this class, it supports parsing extra metadata such as exposure and data compression information as well as setting extra metadata such as GPS and datetime information."* It seems like most of your missing tags can be found there.

Comment: Oh thank you very much @HaraldK it seems you are right indeed i will be using this !